# Hacer scroll caja por caja

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Quiero que la función que tengo haga el scroll mostrando caja por caja con la misma clase y no como lo hace normalmente moviendo el scroll sin importar que caja muestre.

```
<button onclick="nextBox()">Adelante</button>
<button onclick="previousBox()">Atras</button>

<div id="scroll">
<div class="caja-por-caja"></div>
<div class="caja-por-caja"></div>
<div class="caja-por-caja"></div>
</div>

<style>
#scroll{
overflow: auto;
}
</style>

<script>
function nextBox(){
document.getElementById('scroll').scrollLeft = 100;
}
function previousBox(){
document.getElementById('scroll').scrollLeft = -100;
}
</script>
```

Comment: En `css` dentro de la clase `caja-por-caja` puede agregar `overflow: scroll;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No creo que haga falta utilizar javascrip o jquery. Simplemente desde `css` puede utilizar la propiedad `overflow: scroll`.

Aqui te dejo un simple ejemplo.

En mi caso utilice `overflow-y: scroll;` que especifica qué hacer con los bordes superior e inferior del contenido cuando hay un desborde en el `div`.

Puede leer un poco mas en [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_overflow.asp) si lo deseas o buscar mas info en google.

```css
.caja-por-caja {
width: 200px;
height: 100px;
overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="caja-por-caja">
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</div>
<br>
<div class="caja-por-caja">
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</div>
<br>
<div class="caja-por-caja">
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</div>
```

Comment: No creo que sea eso lo que quiere el OP. Suppongo que lo que quiere hacer es desplazarse de una caja a otra